# Video Player frame appearing after transition on SceneManager.LoadScene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using SceneManager.LoadScene to load scenes that use Unity's new Video Player component. Given the momentary stalling that occurs on 360 film while the previous scene is being destroyed – I decided to use a RawImage animation as a transition from completely transparent to black. This masks the problem, but just before the next video loads a frame from the previous video appears after the transition and before the LoadScene, which immediately proceeds it. Any ways to resolve this would be greatly appreciated! The code relevant to this is as follows:

```
sphere.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>().Pause();
rawImage.GetComponent<Animation> ().Play ("FadeOut");
yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.5f); //matches length of time of animation
SceneManager.LoadScene (scene_Name);
```

[image]

I was advised to do this all in a script, but using the code below I am having the exact same issue.

```
rawImage.GetComponent<RawImage> ().enabled = true;
sphere.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>().Pause();
for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
    float transitionCounter = i / 100f;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.0001f);
    Color temp = rawImage.GetComponent<RawImage> ().color;
    temp.a = transitionCounter;
    rawImage.GetComponent<RawImage> ().color = temp;
}
SceneManager.LoadScene (scene_Name);
```

Thanks!

Comment: How are you playing the video? The answer depends on that.

Comment: Video is set to Play on Awake.

Comment: If you are not playing video from script then post a screenshot of the VideoPlayer component in the Inspector tab.

Comment: I've updated the question with a screenshot attached.

Comment: Ok. I see that you are showing the video on a 3D object. Before you load new scene just stop the video. Shouldn't that fix your issue?

Comment: I've tried with both pause and stop and it makes no difference. It is still showing a single frame from the previous video before loading the next scene.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151746/discussion-between-owlwink-and-programmer).

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved this. The easiest solution is to create a timed fade in on the next scene that start from black. That way the frame being carried over is not visible.